# Time complexity of parsing algorithms

Tags: parsing, time-complexity

I want to write a c++ program to parse an input file of the following form.

```
input $input1, $in2, $anotherinput, $a, $b, $x;
output $out1, $out2, $k;
$xyz = $a + $b + $x;
$k = $xyz - $in2;
........
........
.......
$out1 = $k + $b;
```

Input file can have more than 10,000 lines. But most of the lines will be of the form `$A = $B + $C`. Which will be the most efficient parsing algorithm to be used in terms of time complexity.

Comment: Write a grammar and build the parser with bison or yacc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for the simplest algorithm. I suggest Recursive descent prasing.

Answer (score 3):

The question isn't entirely clear but nearly any approach I can imagine has time complexity O(N) where N is the number of lines in your file.    The language you have described is very simple.

Comment: You mean a recursive descent parser and an operator precedence parser will give almost the same time complexity in this case.